# parsing unsigned char pointer to bit operand c++

Tags: c++, linux, pointers, binary

I have a pointer to a raw Ethernet packet that I want to print the IP version of. I'm using C++ on a Linux Client.

The IP version is stored on the 14th byte of the packet header together with IHL (Internet Header Length). I have a function that prints all fields in the IP header, but since the IP version is stored in the 14th byte together with IHL I have to print the first 4 bits in the 14th byte and I have no idea how to do this. I want to print both the IP version and the IHL.

My function goes like so:

```
int PrintIPHeader(unsigned char *eth_head)
{
    unsigned char *ip_head = eth_head;
    int j;

    printf("---Start of IP Header---");
    printf("\nVersion\n");
    for(j = 0; j < 1; j++)
    {
        printf("%d", *(ip_head+j));
    }

    printf("\nIHL\n");
    for(j = 0; j < 1; j++)
    {
        printf("%d", *(ip_head+j));
    }

    printf("\nToS\n");
    for(j = 1; j < 2; j++)
    {
        printf("%d", *(ip_head+j));
    }

    printf("\nTotal Length\n");
    for(j = 2; j < 4; j++)
    {
        printf("%d", *(ip_head+j));
    }

    ...
    and so and so on with all the fields of an IP header 
    (I know the for-loop is unnecessary in some of the cases)
}
```

The above method prints the whole byte but what I want is for it to print only the first 4 bits and then I want another "printf" that prints the 4 last bits of the 1st byte. In the above method I parse the 14th byte of the header as the argument.

I was told that I could use the following to switch the first four bits 4 places and thereby overwriting the IHL, which is not what I want.

```
printf(ip_head[14] >> 4);
```

But I get an error "Invalid operands of types 'unsigned char *' and 'int' to binary 'operator>>'".

Anyone got a solution?

Comment: Unrelated: a loop that does this: `for(j = 0; j < 1; j++)` seems utterly pointless to me. Yet it seems to be a recurring theme in this source. Odd.

Comment: @WhozCraig I just did a quick copy-paste of the large code snippets and ended up writing that completely unnecessary for-loop and I wrote that in the code snippet as well. No need to really point that out..

Comment: Why would `ip_head[14]` be a pointer? According to the code shown it is a value of type `unsigned char`.

Comment: @usr I don't quite get what you're talking about? You'll have to elaborate..

Comment: @Zeliax the error message says that it is a `unsigned char *`. Don't you agree? Why does it say that?

Comment: @usr Well it is an `unsigned char *`, of course I agree on that. About that second part.. well that's what my question is all about..

Comment: @Zeliax something is wrong here. Compile this: `unsigned char *ip_head = NULL; ip_head[14] >> 4;`. No compiler error here, right? The code that you posted is probably not what the compiler tried to compile.

Answer (score 1):

If you use this command

```
printf(ip_head[14] >> 4);
```

the bits are not overwritten permanently.
You can compare the behaviour to

```
printf(a + 4);
```

Where a still holds the value as before but printf is handed over a value that is a+4.